# Remove previously appended options

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can remove previously appended options to accommodate new list of options.

The reason why I'm using append instead of html is that html doesn't seem to like arrays when working with options.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
$('.divi_option').on('change',function(){
    var option = $('.divi_option option:selected').text();
    var rm_name;
    $('.rm_option').prop("disabled",false);

    switch(option){
        case 'East':
            rm_name=['Russ Martin','Carey Fischer','Brandon Born','Joe Tocyloski','Phil Hemery','Bob Mancini','Damien Ramondo','Kevin Gang','Andrew Fischer','David Saslowsky','Robert Brazofsky','Joseph Proscia','William Marsalise','Dan Stack','James Broderick'];
        break;
        case 'South':
            rm_name=['Chris Carrelha','Don Connell','Jay O&rsquo; Connor','Dwight Cornell','Eric Indovina','Russ Corby','Chris Boeker','Robert Nelms','Joe Dominguez','Marc Della Pia','Chris Carrelha','Terry Harris'];
        break;
        case 'West':
        break;
        default:
    }
    for(var i=0;i<rm_name.length;i++){
        $('.rm_option').append('<option>'+rm_name[i]+'</option>');
    }
});
```

I just need to remove the options added from the previous selection. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the options in an empty jQuery collection, and set them all with `html()` once instead of inside the loop

```
$('.divi_option').on('change', function () {
    var option  = $('.divi_option option:selected').text();
    var rm_name = [];
    var options = $([]);

    $('.rm_option').prop("disabled", false);

    switch (option) {
        case 'East':
            rm_name = ['Russ Martin', 'Carey Fischer', 'Brandon Born', 'Joe Tocyloski', 'Phil Hemery', 'Bob Mancini', 'Damien Ramondo', 'Kevin Gang', 'Andrew Fischer', 'David Saslowsky', 'Robert Brazofsky', 'Joseph Proscia', 'William Marsalise', 'Dan Stack', 'James Broderick'];
            break;
        case 'South':
            rm_name = ['Chris Carrelha', 'Don Connell', 'Jay O&rsquo; Connor', 'Dwight Cornell', 'Eric Indovina', 'Russ Corby', 'Chris Boeker', 'Robert Nelms', 'Joe Dominguez', 'Marc Della Pia', 'Chris Carrelha', 'Terry Harris'];
            break;
        case 'West':
            break;
        default:
    }
    $.each(rm_name, function (_, item) {
        options = options.add(
            $('<option />', {
                text: item
            })
        );
    });

    $('.rm_option').html(options);
});
```